# Finding a limit of a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

I have this topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ $$\sigma=\{\emptyset\}\cup \big\{\bigcup_{r\in A}\Omega_r, A\subseteq \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} \big\},$$

where $\Omega_r= \big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, (x+2)^2+(y-2)^2<r^2 \big\}$.

The question is to find all the possible limits of $\big(\frac1n,0 \big)$.

I begin by finding the open set that contains the sequence:
$$
\big(\frac1n,0 \big)\in \Omega_r\Longleftrightarrow \big(\frac1n+2 \big)^2+4<r^2\Rightarrow \frac1n<\sqrt{r^2-4}-2\Rightarrow n>\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2-4}-2} $$
then $$ \forall r>\sqrt{8}, \exists n_0= E\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2-4}-2}\right]+1, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}, n\geq n_0\Rightarrow \big(\frac1n,0 \big)\in \Omega_r.$$

What should the conclusion look like?

Comment: Are you sure you copied that correctly? It seems to me that \bigcup_{r\in A}\Omega_r should be equal to **R**.

Comment: What is E??????

Comment: @Acccumulation. I believe that what is intended is that $\sigma$ is the topology generated by the base (basis)  $\{\Omega_r: r>0\},$ although that is not what is written in the Q.

Answer (score 1):

To straighten the twisted definition of the topology,
R^2 is given the base B = { $U_r$ : r > 0 } where
$U_r$ = { (x,y) : $(x + 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2$ < $r^2$ },
an open disk of radius r, centered at (-2,2).

Let t = 2$\sqrt2$, the distance from the center of $U_r$
to (0,0) and C = { (x,y) : $(x + 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2$ = $t^2$ }.

As the space is not Hausdorff, limits of
the sequence (1/n,0) don't have to be unique.

Indeed, every point of C, (0,0) included, is a limit of the
sequence (1/n,0).  An exericise I leave for the reader.

In fact, every point not in $U_t$ is a limit of the sequence (1/n,0).

Comment: how to prove that points in the complement of C are not a limits? @William Elliot

Comment: Is it correct that all $\Omega_r$  with $r>\sqrt{8}$ contains an infinity of element of the sequence as I show?

Comment: How you get the idea of C please

Comment: i think that we must say that the limits are in the set $$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2,(x+2)^2+(y-2)^2\geq t\}$$

Comment: @Vrouvrou.  This not a chat room with quick replies.  Here replies can take hours.   C came about by visualizing.  You are right about the rest if the limits.  See edit.  This is an example of a hyper-connected space.  Show that there is a point p for which {p} is dense.

Comment: @Mirko yes i found that the limits are in $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2,(x+2)^2+(y-2)^2\geq 8\}$